# Git Rebase error:updating the following directories would lose untracked files in them

Tags: git

I have a project branch in Git and after a number of commits into that I'm trying to rebase the Project branch using the command:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

One of the commits done in the project branch has some directory changes like, a set of files have been moved into a new folder.

When the rebasing reaches this step, it fails with the error saying

> error:updating the following directories would lose untracked files in them.

I have tried to look into suggestions to overcome this but couldn't find an answer. I would appreciate any help here.

**Edit:[Solved]** I have found the cause. When the directories were attempted to be moved to a different folder, they were actually copied leaving behind their residue files in the original folder, thus causing Git to identify them as untracked items during rebasing.

However they were not showing up in git status or in TFS changes. Now I had manually removed the residual files and the issue got resolved. Thanks for all those efforts to help me out!

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `git status` in your directory before trying the `rebase`?

Comment: Good question (and tough), but you need to show us more information.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show the output of `git status`

I think that you have untracked files, you need to commit it and than make rebase

`git commit -a -m 'comment'` `git rebase origin/master`